# Image-resource inside ImageButton based on size of the actual button?

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

I got an ImageButton based on this code:

```
ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(this);
    btn.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(someValue,someValue));
    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.some_drawable);
    store.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_other_drawable);    
    store.getBackground().setAlpha(175);
   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Something();

        }
    });
```

The problem with this is that the ImageResource does not change its size according to the size of the actual button. This makes the "some_other_drawable" in my case larger then the actual button even though it is the exact same number of pixels because of the someValue is smaller then the size of the image resource.

How can I make the image resource change according to the size of the actual button?

Answer (score 0):

```
int width = 300;
int height = 100;
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(animal.getBlob(), 0, animal.getBlob().length), width, height, true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
```

resize the image and afterward set it

Comment: What is the "animal" value?

Comment: ohh :D it's a class, i used it to display different kinds of animals and each of these got a picture i resized it to fit on the screen